# Tensorflow output labels is a value in the 2D gird or locating it in the grid

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, data-science, tensorflow2.0

My final output should be a 2D grid that contains values for each grid point. Is there a way to implement in TensorFlow, where I can input a number of images and each image correspond to a specific point in a 2D grid? I want my model such that when I input a similar image it should result in detecting that specific grid in a 2D image. I mean that each image input image belongs to a specific area in the output image (which I divided into a grid for simplicity to make it a finite number of locations).

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit please? - How far you have implemented, which specific point you are not getting, which deep learning model you are using.

Comment: It is not quite clear what you are trying to do. But if it is a classification problem, then you can reshape the output layer as a grid (if possible). Or, distribute the output layer's activation outputs to some grid. Then technically you should be getting the maximum activation output at a certain point in that grid for each specific class. Therefore, set the non-maximum values in the grid to 0.